# Inside server method call, this.connection returns undefined

Tags: meteor

This Meteor server code is expected to `console.log` the client header but the `connection` object is undefined.

How can I get the client header inside the server code? Thanks

//server.js

```
Meteor.methods({
'someName': () => {
    let header = this.connection.httpHeaders;
    console.log(this.connection);
 }
});



// client.js

Meteor.call('someName', params, (err, res) => {

   }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used an arrow function as a method callback. Arrow functions bind the value of `this`, and Meteor cannot override it when your method gets called. Quite a frustrating aspect of JavaScript, I know.

Fix it using a regular JavaScript function:

```
Meteor.methods({
  'someName': function() {
    let header = this.connection.httpHeaders;
    console.log(this.connection);
  }
});
```